# exim dovecot not send email - multiple error exim mainlog

Tags: email, exim, dovecot

I have multiple error in my /var/log/exim/mainlog file. I can not send any mail from my server anymore. For example the prestashop test mail. Configured on the php mail () function is not received.

Do you have an idea ?

-> my ip is not blacklisted
-> telnet myip 25 -> OK

Thank you

recurente errors in mainlog. I do not really understand :

```
2018-03-30 04:38:23 1f1BuH-0006Hw-Et == ln-1@hotmail.fr R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out
2018-03-30 04:39:15 login authenticator failed for (User) [89.248.168.55]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=test@ip)
2018-03-30 04:39:24 1f1SVv-0003Tj-Oh H=mx1.free.fr [212.27.48.6] Connection timed out
2018-03-30 04:39:33 1f19t1-0002df-SS H=mta6.am0.yahoodns.net [67.195.229.59] Connection timed out
2018-03-30 04:40:34 1f1TBH-0004X0-I9 H=xxx.mail.protection.outlook.com [213.199.154.138] Connection timed out
2018-03-30 04:40:34 1f1TBH-0004X0-I9 == order@xxx R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out
2018-03-30 04:40:34 1f1TBH-0004Wm-En == r.stephant@xxx R=virtual_user_unseen T=dovecot_lmtp_udp defer (-44): LMTP error after RCPT TO:<r.stephant@xxx>: 451 4.3.0 <r.stephant@xxx> Temporary internal error
2018-03-30 04:43:51 cwd=/ 4 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -f fail2ban dan@
2018-03-30 04:43:51 cwd=/var/spool/exim 7 args: /usr/sbin/exim -t -oem -oi -f <> -E
2018-03-30 04:43:51 1f1k19-0005eo-LS <= <> U=mail P=local S=5709 T="Mail failure - malformed recipient address" from <> for fail2ban@xxx
2018-03-30 04:43:51 cwd=/var/spool/exim 3 args: /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1f1k19-0005eo-LS
2018-03-30 04:43:51 1f1k19-0005eo-LS ** fail2ban@xxx F=<>: Unrouteable address
2018-03-30 04:43:51 1f1k19-0005eo-LS Frozen (delivery error message)
```

Comment: `[212.27.48.6] Connection timed out` most likely, packets are being dropped by a misconfigured firewall.

Comment: Thanks for your return.

I stopped the fail2ban service and it did not change anything. No emails are received